# Github Actions- Login Jira without using API token

Tags: jira, github-actions

I have a requirement wherein I need to login to JIRA and update a JIRA task.

But in this case I cannot use Jira API TOKEN or JIRA Token.
I am using below code to login but that somehow does not work and login fails:

```
name: JIRA Login thru Github
on: push

jobs:
  Jira Checks:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Jira Checks
    steps:
    - name: Login
      env:
        JIRA_SERVER_URL: ${{ secrets.JIRA_SERVER_URL }}
        JIRA_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.JIRA_USERNAME }}
        JIRA_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.JIRA_PASSWORD }}
      run: |
        echo "Login success"  
        
    - name: Jira issue id extractor
      id: run_tests
      uses: TheRealWaldo/jira-get-issue@v0.0.2
      with:
        search-string: ${{github.event.head_commit.message}}
    - name: Print Jira id
      run: |
         echo ${{steps.run_tests.outputs.issue-key}}
    - name: Print env
      run: |
         echo ${{github.event.head_commit.message}}
      env:
        GITHUB_CONTEXT: ${{ toJson(github) }}
    - name: Transition issue
      uses: atlassian/gajira-transition@master
      with:
        issue: ${{steps.run_tests.outputs.issue-key}}
        transition: "In progress"
```

Comment: How do you plan to use those env variables? API request? Scraping?

Comment: Could [this action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/jira-login) be an option?

Comment: @GuiFalourd this action uses API Token..I can only use Username and Password as secret..

Comment: @GuiFalourd I plan to use these env variables to login to JIRA and then transition a JIRA task from one state to another. so yes with API Request I will be doing so..

Comment: @DannyB Thanks for your direction , I am able to Login now but my transition of JIRA task fails (updated code in question).. with below error:                               Run atlassian/gajira-transition@master
Error: Jira API error
    at Jira.fetch (/home/runner/work/_actions/atlassian/gajira-transition/master/dist/index.js:1:63124) {
  req: {
    method: 'GET',
    body: undefined,
    url: '/rest/api/2/issue/AXESS-4686/transitions'
  },
  originError: TypeError: Only absolute URLs are supported

Comment: @GuiFalourd Thanks for your direction, I am able to login now but my transition phase fails..any suggestions on that? I have updated code in question and below is my error:         Run atlassian/gajira-transition@master
Error: Jira API error
    at Jira.fetch (/home/runner/work/_actions/atlassian/gajira-transition/master/dist/index.js:1:63124) {
  req: {
    method: 'GET',
    body: undefined,
    url: '/rest/api/2/issue/AXESS-4686/transitions'
  },
  originError: TypeError: Only absolute URLs are supported
      at getNodeRequestOptions (/home/runner/work/_actions/